# Decimal is rounded after insert into DB

Tags: php, mysql, insert, decimal, rounding

I've run into a problem upon inserting a decimal with PHP into MySQL. 
The number is formatted as currency, stored in a session variable.

```
$_SESSION['total'];
```

Using number_format to replace the dot with a comma gives me the correct output:

```
$amount= number_format((float)$_SESSION['total'], 2, ",", '');
echo $amount;
//output = 2,85
```

Now I need to insert the variable $amount into the database, which is done like so:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO testtable VALUES" . "('$amount', 'NULL')";
$result = $con->query($query);
```

Upon insert, the number is inserted as "2,00" and not "2,85". I have also tried to do it without number_format but I get the same result.

The row is set as decimal(10,2).

How is it possible that the variable echo's correctly, but the insert rounds it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `number_format()` is a string and the problem is that MySQL / php do not know the comma `,` as a decimal separator so your string `2,85` is cast to a number by using the first characters of your string that are valid number characters.

You should convert your string to a real number before you do any calculations or database inserts by replacing the `,` with a `.` and casting it to a float:

```
$number = (float) str_replace(',', '.', $amount);
```

If your session variables contain actual numbers instead of strings, you should use these directly.

Note that using floats could lead to precision problems / rounding errors. If that is the case, you should use integers only (cents for the amounts for example, so 285 instead of 2.85).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the insert using a point separator , not comma.

```
$amount = number_format((float)$_SESSION['total'], 2, ".", '');
echo $amount; // prints 2.85
$query = "INSERT INTO money (total,second_field) VALUES" . "($amount, 'NULL')";
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

We use number_format() for user easy user readability. In statement
**$amount= number_format((float)$_SESSION['total'], 2, ",", '');**
$amount is string and insertion of string to mysql field with decimal type would insert record with warning

> 1 row inserted. Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column
>   'decimal_test' at row 1

You can use str_replace to remove "," in number and insert value to mysql table as shown below

```
$_SESSION['total'] = "2,85";
$total_in_decimal = str_replace(',', '.', $_SESSION['total']);
$query = "INSERT INTO testtable VALUES" . "('$total_in_decimal', 'NULL')";
$result = $con->query($query);
```